The requested module './../../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
I'm trying to use the TinyMCE editor in a web component with typescript which I have installed via npm:
npm install tinymce@^7

npm install @types/tinymce

After that I imported it
import tinymce from 'tinymce';

Next I go for setting up the initial values:
tinymce.init({   
    selector: '#mytextarea',   
    ... 
});

When I run the application i'm getting the error above.
Can some please point out what I'm doing wrong?
